# Recreate Select Control Options Dynamically jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function which I use to populate a Select control with options. I am grabbing values from objects on the document, and if a condition is met, throwing another value into a Select Control as an option...

```
function dispatchList() {

//grab list element
var list = document.getElementById("techName");

//foreach div assigned the .square class,
$('.square').each(function () {

    //convert each div with .square class toString
    var square = $(this).html().toString();

    //grab availability value
    var availability = $(this).find('tr:eq(4)').find('td').text();

    //grab IP 
    var online = $(this).find('tr:eq(3)').find('td').text()

//if availability and IP values meet below condition...
    if ((availability === "True") && (online.indexOf("10.") === 0)) {

    //grab the name value from this div
        var availableName = $(this).find('tr:eq(0)').find('td').text();

        //create a new option element
        var item = document.createElement("option");

        //create a new text node containing the name of the tech
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(availableName));

        //append the new text node (option) to our select control
        list.appendChild(item);

    }

})
```

}

This function works great, but it runs when the document is ready. I need it to run when the document is ready, but also to recreate this list without refreshing the page. Ideally the select control could be emptied and recreated with a click event on a div.

This is the part I have struggled with. I have the following click event which it would make sense to chain this to, but I have not been able to work it out...

```
function availability() {

//for each element with a class of .square...
$('.square').each(function () {

    //grab the id of each input element (button) contained in each .square div...
    var btnId = $(this).find("input").attr("id");

    //when .square div is clicked, also click it's associated asp button...
    $(this).on('click', function (clickEvent) {

        document.getElementById(btnId).click();

    //****AND ALSO TRIGGER THE dispatchList() FUNCTION TO REBUILD THE #techName LIST****

    })

})
```

}

Can this be done without AJAX or some other post back on the select control?

Does the #techName list need to be emptied first, and then rebuilt?

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".square").on('click', function (clickEvent) {
             var el = clickEvent.target || clickEvent.srcElement

            document.getElementById($(el).find('input').attr("id")).click();
            dispatchList();
    }) 
})
```

That's all i can do with the given question. I didn't test the code. You can give fiddle or anything to test. Also this function is written in the browser.

Comment: Hello Gurkan, thank you for your help! Can you explain what you are doing here?

Comment: when somone clicks the .square it gets the target and clicks the input field, then call dispatchList. And it is evaluated in document ready

Comment: Right, so I have all that working, except dispatchList() doesn't do anything to the list. It only works on page load...so calling dispatchList() does nothing until we reload the page, then the list is correct. This makes me think dispatchList() isn't doing anything from within the function above, but it does run when the document is ready, as specified in another script file.

Comment: Or it could be firing, but the list is for some reason not being recreated.

Comment: On the browser you can put some debugger and see the result by yourself.